I wonder if only advanced mathematical topic discussions are welcomed in math.stackexchange.
I am new to pure mathematics, and I am enthusiastic about it. I posted some questions and answers on math.stackexchange, but received some negative responses.
Sometimes when I was doing my homework or reading the textbook, I came across some difficult problems. I didn't know how to deal with them. I posted the puzzles here, cited the source of the problems, and told them that I have no idea how to deal with it. I am looking for someone to help me, but they said that I am just asking others to do my homework, It's really disrespectful. They left the community rules in the comments, but didn't answer my question, nor did they give me any hints.
Even worse, someone visited my homepage and voted down many of my questions and answers after that. Even if the answer is reasonable, they left no reason. I feel hurt about this. It's unfriendly and I am frustrated. I am still a beginner, and I am unable to post questions about advanced topics. Some problems may be a piece of cake for advanced mathematicians, but they are difficult for me.
I've deleted nearly every posted questions and answers of mine. Maybe I should come back after becoming an advanced mathematics learner? Maybe I won't be blamed for posting those so-called stupid, elementary and worthless questions and answers at that time.

Glad to hear that you are enthusiastic about mathematics. It's important to keep in mind that one of the goals of this site is to be a reference that others will find useful in addressing their own questions. If you post an isolated problem (e.g., from a textbook), it (1) lacks context, and (2) makes it hard for answerers to know how to help. Both are not aligned with the goals of the site, and are likely to attract downvotes and close votes. So, when posting a question, make sure to include all the relevant context and be specific about what you want others to help you with.

Concerning your title. There are many posts on precalculus , elementary number theory or other very basic topics. They are well received (provided context is given and there is not just a question uploaded together with "urgent help"). See for example this post, $8$ hours ago.

When you say "I have no idea how to deal with it", it is almost always that you've not rigorously covered the basics required for the problem yet. Usually, the community only wants attempts by you (alongside context), whatever you've tried throwing at the problem. Failed attempts are not discouraged, because they help others guide you to the solution.

By the way, as Soham Saha has commented, this question fits better at the meta site, so don't be discouraged if this question gets downvoted and/or closed. It's not because this question is poor; it's just it is raised in the wrong place, which is a reasonable error to make for someone not aware of the meta.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Re last comment, whether the topic is advanced is generally irrelevant.  It is sufficient that the posting refers to a math problem that you have been unable to solve, where you followed the protocol article in the last comment.

"Even worse, someone visited my homepage and voted down many of my questions and answers after that." If a user has engaged in serial downvoting against you, that's against the rules, and you should flag your posts for moderator attention and inform them of what's been happening.

I also caution you to not make a habit of deleting your questions or answers you think weren't well received. All questions, whether deleted or not, are considered in terms of "question bans".  So deleting a badly received question will not improve your standing.  The best option is try to edit and improve the closed posts, or down-voted posts, paying attention to the post @user2661923 links you to above How to ask a good question offers great ideas regarding how to improve.

...After a thorough edit, your post will automatically be submitted in "the reopen queue", and possibly be reopened.

@amWhy FYI, your comment's "your post will automatically be submitted in "the reopen queue" " is no longer quite true. As of about a year or two ago, this was changed as explained in the the network Meta's FAQ "How do you reopen a closed question?" answer where, in the "Editing to Reopen" section, it says "The question will only be added to the queue if you check the box to indicate that the question's original close reason has been addressed". I don't recall the post announcing this change, but I can try to find it if you really want.

Thanks, @John, for the update.  Appreciated!

One question from the OP that I know: Pick six integers between 0 and 9 (inclusive). Then two of them must add up to 9. Why?, posted and deleted not too long before this question.

Thank you all for your advice! I have figured out the answer of that question @peterwhy. I will improve my way of asking questions then.
